# Improving scatter plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, figure, scatter

I have to do the scatter plot of a 2-dimensional region in Matlab.

The collection of the points (x,y) that should be included in the scatter is obtained by running a computationally intense code. As a result, this is the scatter that I get [image]

I don't like the picture because in principle there should be no white dots (i.e., spaces among the scatter dots) inside the blue region. The white dots are there because, given that the points to be included in the scatter are obtained by running a computationally intense code, as a result I get a very coarse grid of points to plot.

I tried to cheat by increasing the size of the scatter dots but the result is even worse as the region looks more and more waving on the borders.

Is there anything I could do to "manually" fill the white spaces inside the blue area? Other ideas?

Comment: How about increasing the size of only those points which are not at the borders?

Comment: Thanks: how can I do that?

Comment: Find border points; plot them separately with smaller marker. Plot other points with bigger marker

Comment: is there a pre-built code to find border point? thanks

Comment: It looks like you want to draw a rectangle? Could you provide some more details of this grid? Is it regularly spaced? If so, an `image` might be a better way of showing your output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole region to be filled, a patch object might be better suited to your needs. Not knowing how you're generating the points, that might be easier said than done. If you are systematically searching the whole area or something like that, it shouldn't be too hard to identify the edges, or define small patches for each square space on the plot.